# Java Controller in Kotlin SpringBoot project

Tags: java, spring, kotlin

The new/empty project stub was generated using Spring Initializer on IntelliJ using Kotlin as the language choice along with Gradle.

However, adding a Java controller to the project root does not seem to be found when the application is run. All endpoints return a 404. I tested a Kotlin controller and it is working as expected.

Example Java Controller:

```
@Controller
public class TestController {
    @PostMapping("/")
    public String test() {
        return "test";
    }
}
```

Example Kotlin Controller:

```
@Controller
class TestController {
    @GetMapping("/")
    fun test(model: Model): String {
        return "test"
    }
}
```

build.gradle.kts:

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.5.5"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.11.RELEASE"
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.5.31"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.5.31"
}

group = "com.example"
version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom(configurations.annotationProcessor.get())
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    compileOnly("org.projectlombok:lombok")
    annotationProcessor("org.projectlombok:lombok")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjsr305=strict")
        jvmTarget = "11"
    }
}

tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Comment: "What am I missing?" Minimum, reproducible code. There could be several reasons for your issue, in order to properly replicate it (and support!) I'd suggest you to push your code (only the required parts) to a public git repo

Comment: The new/empty project was simply created from Spring initializer as described. I have added two example controllers I used to test the issue.

Comment: Did you check if the package under which the java controller is present has a component scan on? If not try adding @ComponentScan for it.

Comment: I did try that @AmitMahajan, however IntelliJ warns me that it is redundant and it also does not fix the issue. My guess is that Spring only scans .kt files and not .java files. Is this configurable somewhere?

Comment: can you share the contents of config files?

Comment: attched the build.gradle.kt file. Is there anything else you'd like to see? @AmitMahajan

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using Spring MVC. Are you sure that you have a view "test"? Because it can also be an issue. Try to annotate it with `RestController` instead of `Controller` and see if it's returning anything. For purpose of that test I would remove method parameter too

Comment: Tried all these suggestions, however no luck!

Comment: @John it works fine, make sure you have @ComponentScan("example") on the kotlin DemoApplication, and the same matching package example is there under source main java containing your Java controller. Also, map it to a different path. If it still doesn't work, create the project again and import again.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine for me.
Make sure you put the java controller under source -> main -> java directory and not under source -> main -> kotlin
Make sure java is enabled when you import the project in Intellij.

Here are the settings:
DempApplication:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("example")
class DemoApplication

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<DemoApplication>(*args)
}
```

Java Controller:

```
@RestController
public class UserController {
    @GetMapping("/user")
    public String test() {
        return "test";
    }
}
```

Dependencies:

```
implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    compileOnly("org.projectlombok:lombok")
    runtimeOnly("org.hsqldb:hsqldb")
    annotationProcessor("org.projectlombok:lombok")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
```